# Load a table with NO geometry_column using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I had to backup a PostGIS model in a geopackage and I wonder how to load a non-spatial table, aka a table with NO geometry_column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just had to write None instead of the geometry_column name in the setDataSource method.

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("MyServerAdress", "5432", "myBase", "user", "pass")
uri.setDataSource(schema, table, None)
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), table, "postgres")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

Comment: In my case, it was necessary to add a primary key: `uri.setDataSource(schema, table, None, aKeyColumn='id')`. Without it, the table was invalid.