# How to read postgres sql Table (No geometry) in PYQGIS?

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, table

In my database there is a table without geometry. how to read that from from pyqgis.

```
self.uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
self.uri.setConnection(self.Hostname, self.Portid, self.Dbname, self.Username, self.Password)
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
db.setHostName(self.uri.host())
db.setDatabaseName(self.uri.database())
db.setPort(int(self.uri.port()))
db.setUserName(self.uri.username())
db.setPassword(self.uri.password())
self.dbresult = db.open()
self.uri.setDataSource(self.Schema, "project_ids", "geom", "")
lay = QgsVectorLayer(self.uri.uri(True), "project_ids", "postgres")

print("Layer fields Names",lay.fields().names())
```

is shows not showing any fields How to read the No geometry Tables in pyqgis?

Comment: Try changing `self.uri.setDataSource(self.Schema, "project_ids", "geom", "")` to `self.uri.setDataSource(self.Schema, "project_ids", None, "")`. See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368186/load-a-table-with-no-geometry-column-using-pyqgis

Comment: @JGH Yes its the answer